# Is there a way to send FCM notification to a user data input in Firebase DB?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a project where when the user enters his trade reuirements to the application its data gets saved in Firebase database. is there a way to send push notification this user's device when he enters the data in  firebasedatabase using firebase push notifications

Comment: Sounds like [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) is the one you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way,When user enter the data into the firebasedatabase.
 On Response Successfully,You can set the value against that currently user in firebasedatabase user node. Then using addValueListener of firebase database to check that value which you set if exist then create a push notification like this

```
    NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notify=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.setContentTitle(tittle)
.setContentText(body)
                   .setContentTitle(subject)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc)
.build();

notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notif.notify(0, notify);
```

After this set value to null after push notification.
I hope its helpful for you!